# How to use mapping method of base class for derived class?

Tags: python, types, orm, mapping, derived-class

Imagine I have the following in python (actual language does not really matter, since I have the problem in other languagues like php too. A base class "CarModel" and a derived class "TruckModel" from "CarModel".

```
class CarModel:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__wheel_count: int = 0

    def set_wheel_count(self, value: int) -> None:
        self.__wheel_count = value

class TruckModel(CarModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.__load_in_kg: int = 0

    def set_load_in_kg(self, value: int) -> None:
        self.__load_in_kg= value
```

If I now have a mapping class, which should convert e.g. a Dict to my Model, how can I reuse the mapping-method for my derived class?
Especially if I have a base class with a lot of setter-methods, I have to repeat the code, which I don't like ("dry").

```
class VehicleMapper:
    def map_car_dict_to_car_model(dict: Dict) -> CarModel:
        model: CarModel = CarModel()
        model.set_wheel_count(dict['wheelCount'])
        return model

    def map_truck_dict_to_truck_model(dict: Dict) -> TruckModel:
        model: TruckModel= TruckModel()
        model.set_load_in_kg(dict['loadInKg'])
 
        model.set_wheel_count(dict['wheelCount']) #  ??? How can I re-use the map-method for the base class here ???
        
        return model
```

I could move the mapping methods to the model classes, then this would work. But I got teached, that model classes should only "hold" data and shouldn't do anything. That's why there are mapper classes, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more cleaner and *solid* way is to use separate mappers/factories.
And it's even more justified as in your case you also need a configurable mapping from dict keys to respective model property name.

Consider the following pattern:

```
class CarModel:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__wheel_count: int = 0

    def wheel_count(self, value: int) -> None:
        self.__wheel_count = value

    wheel_count = property(None, wheel_count)

class TruckModel(CarModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.__load_in_kg: int = 0

    def load_in_kg(self, value: int) -> None:
        self.__load_in_kg= value

    load_in_kg = property(None, load_in_kg)


class VehicleFactory:
    """Vehicle base factory"""
    __model__ = None
    __map_keys__ = None

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, data):
        model = cls.__model__()
        for k, attr in cls.__map_keys__.items():
            setattr(model, attr, data[k])
        return model

class CarFactory(VehicleFactory):
    __model__ = CarModel
    __map_keys__ = {'wheelCount': 'wheel_count'}

class TruckFactory(VehicleFactory):
    __model__ = TruckModel
    __map_keys__ = {'wheelCount': 'wheel_count',
                    'loadInKg': 'load_in_kg'}
```

---

Usage:

```
car = CarFactory.create({'wheelCount': 4})
print(vars(car))    # {'_CarModel__wheel_count': 4}

truck = TruckFactory.create({'wheelCount': 4, 'loadInKg': 500})
print(vars(truck))  # {'_CarModel__wheel_count': 4, '_TruckModel__load_in_kg': 500}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Roman!
That's a very nice approach, I like especially the mapping part within the factories.
The only thing is, I tend to avoid magic methods, like setattr() etc. The problem with that is, that "in my opinion" the code gets less readable. In my IDE I can't right click on a function and ask for "show usages" or similar. So I tend to hardcode everything. But I guess with this approach there is no solution, so I will go with your way! 
Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner approach would be to use a decorator function to annotate each setter method with the key that would map to it, and store the key-to-setter mapping as a class attribute, so that keys and setters for `CarModel` can be resued for `TruckModel`, and no names of keys or setters are repeated when building the mapping, better adhering to the DRY principle:

```
class FromDictable:
    key_to_setter = {}

    @classmethod
    def bind_key(cls, key):
        def decorator(setter):
            cls.key_to_setter[key] = setter
        return decorator

    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls, d: dict):
        instance = cls()
        for key, value in d.items():
            cls.key_to_setter[key](instance, value)
        return instance

bind_key = FromDictable.bind_key

class CarModel(FromDictable):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__wheel_count: int = 0

    @bind_key('wheelCount')
    def set_wheel_count(self, value: int) -> None:
        self.__wheel_count = value

class TruckModel(CarModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.__load_in_kg: int = 0

    @bind_key('loadInKg')
    def set_load_in_kg(self, value: int) -> None:
        self.__load_in_kg= value
```

so that:

```
print(vars(CarModel.from_dict({'wheelCount': 4})))
print(vars(TruckModel.from_dict({'wheelCount': 6, 'loadInKg': 8000})))
```

outputs:

```
{'_CarModel__wheel_count': 4}
{'_CarModel__wheel_count': 6, '_TruckModel__load_in_kg': 8000}
```

Demo [here](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=lVNPS8MwFD9466fIbQ1spQeRUVCEiSCiJ28ioWtet7IsGWk6GWOfxMsu-k38En4aX9qmjYON2dvL-_15v5fm42u1MXMl9_vPyuSj8c_FdybSsiT3Wi3visykUwFJQPBbwIYZxUowBjS5JttdUJ_f1oQloAyvDzjkZFpIzpARZqIcWiptRFyfQ6Z0apQOGz2vbT9kRX_8XrF6Q9Om6rAaTKVlr3ZiohwDMY6JmpF4Qmzh-RayNKnMAF0QEdKukSttEwzJOhUVII7wqDCwRMw5U4dOuBWgh9O7fhC4reEI_v4jdx4EzeVMUv2kOIjQR7XD2KyMFbIwjOFyRe4NacuIsfc5gGCZqqRJ0N2gXdxurru3QQ2aWMyAdsIYy2fX-m2sWomS0Q15VhJOeaJdzXBpXnSVLZo8Ltg5WaoV6JBGXZ8eWgqVcmyyxex4Sot5kI-zg4w99R8Re1IXcKWREa5TXXbRov5H3PpLTsjljlLqU_rFHCddDUkfIiHjOI6tTPOa20ftHvcv)